# What $f(t)$ satisfies the inverse Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{p'(s)}{p(s)}\right\}=f(t),$ where the polynomial $p$ is given.

Tags: laplace-transform

What is the general form of $f(t)$ in the inverse Laplace transform $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{p'(s)}{p(s)}\right\}=f(t),$$ for some given polynomial $p(s)$ ?

Put another way, what $f(t)$ satisfies the Laplace transform $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} = \frac{p'(s)}{p(s)},$$ where the polynomial $p(s)$ is given.

Comment: Here is an example $f(t)=e^{t},\,e^{-t}$.

Comment: By the way, why are you interested in this problem or in other words where it came from?

Comment: Came from looking at the properties of the Laplace transform. My book, "Table of Integrals, Series and Products" by Gradshteyn et al only has the basic properties in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=\text{deg}(p)$ be the degree of the polynomial $p$. Then by partial fractions we may write $$\frac{p'(s)}{p(s)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{A_k}{s-\sigma_k},$$ for some $A_k$, where $p(\sigma_k)=0$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$. But since $\frac{1}{s-a}=\mathcal{L}\left\{e^{-at}\right\}$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{A_k}{s-\sigma_k}=\sum_{k=1}^n A_k\mathcal{L}\{e^{-\sigma_k t}\}=\mathcal{L}\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n A_ke^{-\sigma_kt}\right\}.$$ Hence, $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{p'(s)}{p(s)}\right\}=\sum_{k=1}^n A_ke^{-\sigma_kt}.$$ It may be that the right hand side has closed form due to the exponential forms of the sine and cosine functions, depending on our choice of $p$.

Note - this generalises the original question since $p'/p\equiv q/p$, where $\text{deg}(q)<\text{deg}(p)$.

However, in the original case for $p'/p$, it appears that $A_k=1$ for all $k$, in which case there will indeed be closed fom in terms of sines, cosines, and their hyperbolic equivalents.